# Xamarin Get image path from intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

I'm trying to get the path from the image that I want to share from image gallery to my app.

```
[IntentFilter( new [] {Intent.ActionSend}, Categories = new [] { Intent.CategoryDefault}, DataMimeType = "image/*" )]
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
{
   if (keys.Contains(Intent.ExtraStream)) 
   {

       var uri = (Android.Net.Uri)Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream);
       var path = uri.Path;

       Console.WriteLine (uri);
       Console.WriteLine (path);
   }
}
```

I get this as output :

URI : 
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F19820/ACTUAL

PATH : 
/0/1/content://media/external/images/media/19820/ACTUAL

But what is ACTUAL... how can I get the filename to be able to open the image...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally,

[I found my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858881/how-to-add-your-application-to-the-share-menu-with-monodroid)

I had to send the uri to this nice method :

```
private string GetFilePath(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data};
        //Deprecated
        //var cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        var cursor = ContentResolver.Query (uri, proj, null, null, null);
        var colIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        return cursor.GetString(colIndex);
    }
```